# Control a PPTX file with Javascript offline

Tags: javascript, iframe, ms-office, powerpoint, offline

This is an odd use-case and I've tried to steer the users away from this, but I have a request to load locally stored PPT files in an HTML environment.

The idea is to view the PPT in an iframe so that I can "decorate" all around it. Users will be creating playlists, of sorts, so I need to add "next" and "previous" presnetation buttons, etc.

I have an online version of this working using the Office webapp link that many other posts have shared, but there is a concern for poor connectivity so they want it to be available offline.

My instinct was to shape this up as a PWA. I can make them use Chrome, so I have the FileSystem API "caching" the PPT files from the online source. However, I have no way to render the saved files!

Because it's offline, I can't use googledocs or continue to MS web office.

I don't know the AppCache feature well enough, but wondered if I can preload all of the docs in an iframe, will it cache those. My thought is that it won't, because the content is on microsoft (or Google's) site.

All users will have a legal copy of PPT on the computer, if that helps at all.

So far I have tried storing the files using the filesystem API in combination with the Chrome offline viewer extension and alternatively the Native Docs extension.  The Chrome one will allow me to open a doc, but directly in edit mode. I need to simulate the behavior of a ppsx file, but neither extension works with ppsx files and I don't see documentation for an API that will allow me to "auto-play" the presentations.

Thanks for any ideas!

Wayne

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/623529/libreoffice-firefox-plugin

Comment: Have you tried using LibreOffice?

Comment: When you say "have you tried..." what do you mean?

Comment: Meaning what approaches have you tried to resolve the inquiry? For example, incorporating the use of an existing or creating a browser extension to meet the requirement?